# How to take a string out of a set

Tags: c++, string

Does anyone know how to take a string out of a set and then initialize that string to a new variable?  For example, say you have "Hello world" at the beginning of the list and then "hello baby" . How can I take the line "Hello world" out and place it in a new string variable? Here's the code that I made (trying to get unique words from a set of lines btw):

Comment: Just placed it above^

Comment: Please use meaningful variable names.  You have "wl_1" "wl_2" "it" "temp" and "temp2".  All of that is virtually meaningless, which makes your code harder to understand for no benefit.

Comment: @brokenfoot don't suggest people to use strcpy() in C++. Even in C is not a good function, there are better alternatives

Comment: `set::erase` removes things from a set -- you can call it either with a value (to look up that value and erase it) or an iterator (to erase the value the iterator refers to).  What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to go through each line in a set and copy each line to a new string variable. For what I'm actually working on is figuring out a way to count the number of unique words a set has. What I have to do is break each string down into separate words and then place those words in a set to then get the unique words.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <set>
using namespace std;

template <typename InIt> set<string> TokenSet(InIt begin, InIt end)
{
    static const string chars = { ' ', '\f', '\n', '\r', '\t', '\v', '\0' };

    set<string> result;
    string::size_type pos1, pos2;

    for (; begin != end; begin++)
    {
        const string &str = *begin; // If InIt doesn't refer to string, compile error will occur
        pos1 = 0;
        while (1)
        {
            pos2 = str.find_first_of(chars, pos1);
            result.insert(str.substr(pos1, pos2 - pos1));
            if (pos2 == string::npos)
                break;
            pos1 = str.find_first_not_of(chars, pos2);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    set<string> source = { "Hello world", "Hell world", "Hello guys" };
    set<string> out = TokenSet(source.begin(), source.end());
    copy(out.begin(), out.end(), ostream_iterator<string>(cout, " "));
}
```

Output:

```
Hell Hello guys world
```

Comment: Oops I see there's bug.. please wait

Answer (score 0):

Here's a rewritten version.  I think this does about the same as your original, but more simply and hopefully more clearly.  Once it's been refactored like this, it is fairly obvious that you are forgetting to actually break the strings once you find the whitespace between them.  You had `.substr()` with no arguments which is definitely not what you want.

So don't consider this to be a fixed version of your code, but rather a way to see how to fix your code.

```
// split inPhrases on whitespace, add each word to outWords
// return total size of outWords (including anything that was there before)
size_t countUniqueWords(const set<string>& inPhrases, set<string>& outWords)
{
  for (set<string>::iterator it = inPhrases.begin(); it != inPhrases.end(); it++)
  {
    for (size_t ii = 0; ii < it->size(); ii++)
    {
      if (!isspace((*it)[ii]))
      {
        outWords.insert(*it);    
      }
    }
  }
  return outWords.size();
}
```